# Google Cloud DNS access my server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-dns

I very new in Google Cloud. Previously I worked with AWS and the route53 solution is very easy.

I have enabled billing.

I configured a new zone in my cloud:

[image]
So I browse Google DNS but...
[image]

But if browse the ip direct ;

[image]

Please Help Me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the Google nameservers (viewable in your first screenshot i.e. ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com, ns-cloud-a2.googledomains.com etc) as the custom name servers for your domain name provider?

I feel this may be the issue.

If you haven't, navigate to your domain name providers website, select the relevant options to manage your domain, and add the Google domain name server addresses in your screenshot as custom nameservers (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/dns/update-name-servers) for more information on this). Wait a few minutes for the change to take a affect and then see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: Sorry but I Don't understand the ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com may be added to /etc/resolv  in my instance o my server ??

Comment: No I didn't mean that. You would have registered your domain name with a company/web service. What I meant was you need to navigate to the site and manage your domain name at the site. There should be an option there to add the name servers. I've added a link to my answer for you to take a look at

Comment: Ok, so 

I buy  domain name in godaddy for example and godaddy I added the DNS ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com if?